# Invalidate Instant Campaign Content in DXA 2.2 . Sites 9.1

Tags: dxa, dxa2.2, sites-9.1, .net

I am using Instant Campaign module for managing the landing pages comes as zip package. I am facing one issue while updating the content of the page.

Once I publish the page and request the page I see there is a folder created automatically which contains zip content.

Path of the directory : `\<ApplicationFolder>\BinaryData\<folder with Publication Tcm ID as folder name>\campaign-content\<folder with Component TCMID as folder name>`

[image]

In order to have the updated content I have to follow the below steps:

1. Delete the folder which contains the actual content
2. Recycle the app pool
3. Request the page

After executing the above steps I see the folder is again created with updated content.

Is there any other way to invalidate the cache. As for other normal DXA pages I don't see any issue with content updation. These contents are automatically updated after publishing. (Using AMQ service).

What I observed the page is being cached at IIS level. Even if I delete the folder the page works fine as it is being cached at IIS.

Can any one suggest how to handle this. As recycling  the app pool is not a good practice after each content Publish.

Comment: IIRC we observed something similar with 9.5 - I will see about getting back into the environment and testing to confirm.

Comment: Waiting for your response as well Mark :)

Comment: I can confirm this looks like a bug. The easiest/quickest way around it at the moment would be to simply rename the images folder - if the image folder doesn't exist, all assets are created again in a new `[name] Image` folders. I would suggest raising a ticket with RWS Support ASAP.

Comment: Just seen Nic's response - @manas - did this work?

Comment: Hello Mark . The updated code helped and the issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

What content are you changing? The uploaded campaign ZIP or the textual content stored in Tridion? Instant Campaign is checking the timestamp on the ZIP file (which handled as any other media asset in DXA). If that has changed, the ZIP file will be re-extracted again. Can you verify that the timestamp of the ZIP has changed or not under BinaryData/[publication]/media?

The textual content is handled as ordinary DXA entity, which means it should be available in the same pace as other content (depending on your view model caching etc).

Comment: UPDATE: I did some further tests on this and found one scenario where the re-extraction of the ZIP file is not triggered. I'm right now doing an update of InstantCampaign and I'll post a new version to AppStore shortly.

Comment: New version (v1.3.1) is available now on AppStore that includes a bug fix for this issue + other improvements: 
https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/instant-campaign/748/

All source is available here: 
https://github.com/sdl/dxa-flexible-campaign-content

Comment: Thanks Niclas !! I will test the newer version in our lower environment.

Comment: Hello Niclas!! We applied the fix in our environment and it resolved the issue. Thanks..

Comment: The new way of validating the updated content using time stamp over the regex expression helped.

Comment: Good news Manas!